# Not equal to comparison operator does not work

Tags: opportunity, operators

I have a list of opportunities that I fetched via SOQL query. I am trying to check if any of the fetched opportunities is 'Closed Lost' or 'Closed - Lost'or 'Completed' or 'Closed Won'. If not, then I am storing that particular opportunity in a separate opportunity variable.

I have this:

```
     Opportunity temp=null;
     for(Opportunity opp: opportunities)

        {

            if(opp.StageName <> 'Closed Lost' || opp.StageName <> 'Closed - Lost' || opp.StageName <> 'Completed' || opp.StageName <> 'Closed Won')
                {temp=opp;}
        }


    System.debug('Opportunity open or not check temp' + temp);

    if(temp==null)

            {

                .....................

             }
```

Even though the stage comes out to be other than those four, temp variable is not null. Any idea why is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This logic doesn't work:

```
opp.StageName <> 'Closed Lost' || opp.StageName <> 'Closed - Lost' || opp.StageName <> 'Completed' || opp.StageName <> 'Closed Won'
```

to find Opportunities that don't have any of those stages. Suppose the `StageName` is `Closed Lost`. The first clause evaluates to `false`, but the second one, `opp.StageName <> 'Closed - Lost'`, evaluates to `true`. Then, because this is an OR comparison, the whole Boolean expression evaluates to `true`, and your variable gets set.

If what you want is to determine if the Opportunity's stage name *isn't* any one of a number of stages, you need to use AND logic (`&&`), or add the Stage Names to a `Set<String>` and ask the set if it `.contains(opp.StageName)`.

Comment: wow, such a silly mistake. Thank you so much. It worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the `<>` operator does in apex. [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm) is a list of the operators you should use for comparisons.

try this:

```
Opportunity temp=null;

Set<String> stages = new Set<String>{'Closed Lost', 'Closed - Lost', 'Completed', 'Closed Won'};

for(Opportunity opp: opportunities){
    System.debug('the opp:' + opp.Id + 'Stage: ' opp.StageName);
    if(stages.contains( opp.StageName)){
        temp = opp;
        break;
    }
}


System.debug('Opportunity open or not check temp' + temp);
```